# Bash file with for loop and ssh

Tags: bash, matlab

I would like your help to solve the following problem arising when I try to execute a simple for loop using a bash file.

---

I have two very simple Matlab scripts

**1) main.m**

```
clear
rng default
P=2;
grid=randn(2,3);
jobs=1;
```

**2) f.m**

```
sgetasknum_grid=grid(jobs*(str2double(getenv('SGE_TASK_ID'))-1)+1: str2double(getenv('SGE_TASK_ID'))*jobs,:); %jobsx3

result=sgetasknum_grid+1; 

filename = sprintf('result.%d.mat', ID);
save(filename, 'result')

exit
```

**What I want to do:**

- I want to run main.m;
- then, I want to run f.m twice
- Everything should be executed on node **A**

---

Here's my attempt

**1)** I save main.m and f.m into a folder named My_folder

**2)** I create the bash file td.sh as below and save it into the folder My_folder

```
    #$ -S /bin/bash
    #$ -l h_vmem=5G
    #$ -l tmem=5G
    #$ -l h_rt=480:0:0
    #$ -cwd
    #$ -j y


    #$ -N try

    date
    hostname

    for SGE_TASK_ID in {1..2}
do
    #Output the Task ID
    echo "Task ID is $SGE_TASK_ID"

  /share/.../matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r "main; ID=$SGE_TASK_ID; f; exit"
done
```

**3)** I go into the terminal and type `ssh username@A`, then `cd /.../My_folder`, then `bash td.sh`

---

Questions: steps **1),2),3)** above don't do what I want
and this is the what I get as output on the terminal

```
A.local
Task ID is 1

                                                                 < M A T L A B (R) >





Nonfinite endpoints or increment for colon operator in index.

Error in f (line 2)
sgetasknum_grid=grid(jobs*(str2double(getenv('SGE_TASK_ID'))-1)+1: str2double(getenv('SGE_TASK_ID'))*jobs,:); %jobsx3
>>
```

I don't get why is giving me this error. (I don't even know how to get back to the normal terminal and "remove" the `>>` symbol). Indeed,  when I execute cg.sh typing `qsub cg.sh` instead of `bash cg.sh` things work out perfectly.

---

**Update:** when I execute cg.sh locally typing `bash cg.sh` on the terminal, Matlab seems to prefer `str2num` in place of `str2double` in the script f.m. With `str2num` in place of `str2double` everything works. Though, I'm not understanding why and your point of view would be very helpful.

Comment: In your code, make sure that there is not **space** in the assignment statement in bash. For example, instead of `ID = $SGE_TASK_ID` but `ID=$SGE_TASK_ID`

Comment: Golden rule of bash questions: try [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) first

Comment: @eapetcho Done, the output has changed but still doesn't do what I want.

Comment: Do you actually need both qsub and ssh? Isn't ssh enough to get the program running on node A?

Comment: @jeremysprofile Thanks for the tip: I get an error in line 1: `SC2148: Tips depend on target shell and yours is unknown. Add a shebang.`  I'm sorry, but I don't understand what that means, I've always written line 1 that way.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks. I don't know: once the bash file has been saved into My_folder, how do you "execute" it?

Comment: What is the default shell of the server you're connecting to? If it's bash, just put `#!/bin/bash` at the top when you paste it in to shellcheck.

Comment: @jeremysprofile thanks, now the shellneck does not detect mistakes. Still, I don't get what I want..

Comment: @user3285148 You can use `bash td.sh` instead of `qsub td.sh` to run it locally

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks, see my updated question, I'm still having troubles.

Comment: @user3285148 Are you able to run and test your matlab code from a terminal outside of the script?

Comment: @thatotherguy I'm fixing things step by step, thanks for your patience. Now the issue is that when I run locally using `bash` Matlab is giving me a mistake. When I use `qsub` instead everything works perfectly.  I've updated the question.

Comment: SGE_TASK_ID would normally be set by `qsub`, but you assign it manually in your script. You can use `export SGE_TASK_ID` to make sure that manually assigned variable is available to matlab

Comment: @thatotherguy Where should I write that? Should I delete something from `td.sh`?  I've also noticed that if I use `str2num` in place of `str2double` in the script `f.m` then everything works. But I don't know why. This problem does not appear when I execute using `qsub`

Comment: You can put it basically anywhere before the matlab command. The line before the loop might be a good location.

Comment: @thatotherguy Thanks, with that line now it works also with `str2double`. Thanks

Comment: @thatotherguy I have another question on this, where I try to parallelise https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632426/parallelise-for-loop-in-bash Please help in case you have some time